# Predecessor lag converted into 4800 in MS Project while save it as XML

Tags: ms-project

**Description**

If I have provided 1 day lag in predecessor's then it is converted into 4800 while saving it as XML

Please find the prepared link I have created in MS Project

Predecessor with lag:

[image]

Please find the link lag in XML:

[image: link lag in XML]

How can I find the calculation behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MS Project's standard calendar, the calculation seems to be the duration in minutes (One 8hr work day = 480 minutes of duration) multiplied by 10 (480 x 10 = 4800).

Comment: XML documentation for the [LinkLag Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-project/xml-data-interchange/linklag-element?view=project-client-2016) states it is "The amount of lag in tenths of a minute."